# iOS 14 PickerView cutting off text

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I Have a pickerview which does not display text properly as off iOS 14.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  It seems like there is a subview covering the text?

[image: The U is completely cut off]

Is it because I'm using a custom label?

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        let titleData = pickerDataSource[row]
        
        pickerView.subviews[1].backgroundColor = .clear
        pickerView.subviews[0].backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black])
        pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle
        return pickerLabel
    }
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Just updated :)

Comment: Use the View Debugger to find out if something is covering the text.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing, with an even simpler custom label. There's nothing covering the text; you can often see that the new rectangular area contains a few pixels of the first character. So far the only solution I've found is to use center alignment. File a bug report with Apple: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score 5):

Just add margin-left to the label would do the trick.

[After the fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1oUn.png)

Raw code:

```
extension UILabel {
    func setMargins(margin: CGFloat = 10, _ leftMarginOnly: Bool = true) {
            if let textString = self.text {
                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = margin
                paragraphStyle.headIndent = margin
                if !leftMarginOnly {
                    paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -margin
                }
                let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
                attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
                attributedText = attributedString
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The method name should clearly state that this is a bug fix: fixBugMargins. After few weeks when you will be reading a code which use this extension you will ask your self if this is a UIKit method or a custom method. Secondly, this method will be present for all UILabels but the bug is present on UILabel in UIDatePicker. Two possibilities: the method will be moved to UIPickerView or a custom class UIKitBugFixes

Answer (score 1):

You can set the attributedString, as Nguyen suggested, in the ViewForRow method and edit your code like this

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    let titleData = pickerDataSource[row]
    
    pickerView.subviews[1].backgroundColor = .clear
    pickerView.subviews[0].backgroundColor = .clear
    
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black])
    
    let margin : CGFloat = 12.0
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = margin
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = margin
    myTitle.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: myTitle.length))
    
    pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle
    return pickerLabel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an even simpler label-generation method; for now my workaround is to use center alignment, as in the following example.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                viewForRow row: Int,
                forComponent component: Int,
                reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.text = "Test string"
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Ropa Sans", size: 18)
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
}
```

I wondered if this was a font-dependent defect, but since you're using the system font I conclude that it probably isn't.

Answer (score 0):

A hack way is to add code below to `pickerView(viewForRow:)`

```
pickerView.subviews[0].subviews.first?.subviews.last?.clipsToBounds = false
```

`pickerView.subviews[0].subviews.first?.subviews` contains 3 view, and the last one is the real one wrapped your view, its width is smaller than the picker view, so it will trim the real content.